# enum value parameter showing up as null in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project and on my index screen, I'd like to sort by two fields, one is a text field, the other an enumerated field.  I'm able to get the text search to work, but not the enumerated field.  The dropdown box does appear, but the value passed back is always null.

Enum

```
public enum Priority 
{
    Low = 0,
    Medium = 1,
    High = 2,
    Urgent = 3,
    Compliance = 4
}
```

Model

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Priority")]
public Priority Priority { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 1)]
[DisplayName("Requested By")]
public string RequestedBy { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string enumPriority, string searchString)
{
    var PriorityLst = new List<string>();
    var PriorityQry = from d in db.Reports
                      orderby d.Priority.ToString()
                      select d.Priority.ToString();

    PriorityLst.AddRange(PriorityQry.Distinct());
    ViewBag.Priority = new SelectList(PriorityLst);

    var reports = from m in db.Reports
                  select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        reports =             reports.Where(s=>s.RequestedBy.Contains(searchString));
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(enumPriority))
    {
        reports = reports.Where(x => x.Priority.ToString() ==             enumPriority.ToString());
    }
```

View (Index):

```
<p>

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Reports", FormMethod.Get)) 
{
<p> Priority: @Html.DropDownList("Priority", "Select")
    Requested By: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") 

    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
```

Comment: What's the name of the model class that contains both properties? Why not let the model binder do the work?

Comment: The name of the model class is public class Report

Comment: Have you tried changing your Index method to take an object of type Report? The model binder should be able to bind these properties for you : `public ActionResult Index(Report report)`.

Comment: No, I hadn't tried that.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You will need to add the search string parameter too by the way. Consider making it a property of the model so it gets bound automatically as well.

Comment: Change your parameter name from enumPriority to priority

Comment: That would work too @Cory but I think she would be better served with a proper model and binding.

Comment: @Juan Agreed, but I'm not here teaching best practices.. haha. She'll get there, I remember when I was starting just getting a working solution was the first step. Refactoring and learning intricacies about the code comes later.

Comment: Ok I took the easy way out and got it to work.  Thanks!  I did TRY to pass the object but then it wasn't showing my complete database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method signature from:

```
public ActionResult Index(string enumPriority, string searchString)
```

to:

```
public ActionResult Index(string priority, string searchString)
```

That said, as Juan pointed out in the comments, the model binder can do the work for you. It would look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
```

You'd want to make sure it includes all of the properties you need (priority, searchString). The model would also need a default constructor to allow the model binder to create the object. In this small example, it doesn't seem like the extra work would be worth it, but in the future, more complex models, or simply models with many more properties, you'll be glad to pass the work off to the model binder.